# IOS plist Simple Quiz Game

Tags: objective-c, plist

Hi I've been having a problem with a quiz game I have been trying to create and have searched everywhere for the answer but with no luck. I am creating a quiz which reads in a plist file with a number of questions and answers everything works fine except for when I pick an answer the next question will not appear. From using the NSLogs I can see that the increment on the currentQuestion value works it is in fact the self.question that seems to be losing the plist file here is my plist code as I am unable to post an image yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Questions</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
        <string>What is 1 + 1?</string>
        <key>A</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>B</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>C</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>D</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
        <string>D</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
        <string>What is 2 + 2?</string>
        <key>A</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>B</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>C</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>D</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
        <string>A</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
        <string>What is 5 + 2?</string>
        <key>A</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>B</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>C</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>D</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
        <string>C</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
        <string>What is 9 - 2?</string>
        <key>A</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>B</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>C</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>D</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
        <string>C</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
        <string>What is 10 - 6?</string>
        <key>A</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>B</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>C</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>D</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
        <string>A</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>QuestionTitle</key>
        <string>What is 1 + 2?</string>
        <key>A</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>B</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>C</key>
        <string>7</string>
        <key>D</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>QuestionAnswer</key>
        <string>B</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

The tutorial i followed to create this quiz had **Questions** as the main key where I have **Root** as the Key but I cant seem to be able to change the Root name I believe that may fix my problem if someone knows how to change this? I edited the code to work around this anyways, this is my **viewDidLoad** and **showNextQuestion** Note: When any of the buttons A,B,C, or D are pressed showNextQuestion is called.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Questions1" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.questions = [tempDict objectForKey:@"Questions"];

    currentQuestion = -1;
    NSLog(@"%d",currentQuestion);
    [self showNextQuestion];
}

-(void)showNextQuestion
{
    currentQuestion++;
    NSLog(@"%d",currentQuestion);
    NSLog(@"%d",[self.questions count]);
    if(currentQuestion < [self.questions count])
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside the loop");
        NSDictionary *nextQuestion = [self.questions objectAtIndex:currentQuestion];
        self.answer = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"QuestionAnswer"];
        self.lblQuestion.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"QuestionTitle"];
        self.lblQuestionA.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"A"];
        self.lblQuestionB.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"B"];

        if([nextQuestion objectForKey:@"C"]){
            self.lblQuestionC.hidden = NO;
            self.btnC.hidden = NO;

            self.lblQuestionC.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"C"];
        }
        else{
            self.lblQuestionC.hidden =YES;
            self.btnC.hidden = YES;
        }

        if([nextQuestion objectForKey:@"D"]){
            self.lblQuestionD.hidden = NO;
            self.btnD.hidden = NO;

            self.lblQuestionD.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"D"];
        }
        else{
            self.lblQuestionD.hidden =YES;
            self.btnD.hidden = YES;
        }

    }
    else{
        //Game Over
    }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated Thank you in advance

Comment: How is the self.question property or ivar defined? You need to make sure it's a strong reference (what used to be called retain).

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) NSArray *questions;

Comment: Hi sorry i tried to edit my comment earlier on but was unable that was exactly what was wrong it seems so simple now it slipped my mind sorry and thank you very much for the help

Answer (score -1):

```
self.lblQuestionTitle.text = [nextQuestion objectForKey:@"QuestionTitle"];
```

Comment: Maybe you could add a short note to your answer?